# CPU reservation and affinity using taskset and isolcpus kernel parameter with JVM?

Tags: cpu-usage, taskset

We need for the JVM to reserve a set number of CPUs. Following my research we can use `taskset` along with the kernel parameter `isolcpus=<CPU_ID>` so that no other process uses this CPU.

A few questions arise:

- does the process need to be started with `taskset`?
- does the reservation means that the process can only run on that CPU and if there are resources problems it can expand to the other CPUs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use cgroups to limit all processes except whitelist to a single CPU?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247209/how-to-use-cgroups-to-limit-all-processes-except-whitelist-to-a-single-cpu)

Answer (score 0):

You typically use `taskset` to restrict a process after it's been started. You could make use of the `pidof java` to determine what the PID is for your Java application and then pass that to `taskset`:

```
$ taskset -p $(pidof java) --cpu-list 0-2,5
```

**NOTE:** If you had 6 CPUs, 0,1,2,5 would assign an affinity to these CPUs for your JVM's PID.

Keep in mind that affinity does not restrict other processes from using these CPUs, `taskset` if more a tool of restricting a specific process or processes to a specific set of CPUs, not in restricting exclusivity.

*excerpt taskset man page*

> taskset  is used to set or retrieve the CPU affinity of a running process given its PID or to launch a new COMMAND with a given CPU affinity.  CPU affinity is a scheduler property that "bonds" a process
>          to a given set of CPUs on the system.  The Linux scheduler will honor the given CPU affinity and the process will not run on any other CPUs.  Note that the Linux  scheduler  also  supports  natural  CPU
>          affinity: the scheduler attempts to keep processes on the same CPU as long as practical for performance reasons.  Therefore, forcing a specific CPU affinity is useful only in certain applications.

#### Alternatives

This self answered U&L Q&A titled: [How to use cgroups to limit all processes except whitelist to a single CPU?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247209/how-to-use-cgroups-to-limit-all-processes-except-whitelist-to-a-single-cpu) covers the topic of how to accomplish this using cgroups.

#### References

- [Determining the particular processor on which a process is running](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79520/determining-the-particular-processor-on-which-a-process-is-running/79526#79526)

Comment: Is it therefore not possible to reserve cpu exclusivly  to some applications and nothing else uses these cpu?

Comment: It's possible using cgroups - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247209/how-to-use-cgroups-to-limit-all-processes-except-whitelist-to-a-single-cpu. But not in the way you imagine.

Comment: I read on xmodulo that the kernel parameter "isolcpus=<CPU_ID>" to the boot loader during boot or GRUB configuration file. Then the Linux scheduler will not schedule any regular process on the reserved CPU core(s), unless specifically requested with taskset. For example, to reserve CPU cores 0 and 1, add "isolcpus=0,1" kernel parameter. Upon boot, then use taskset to safely assign the reserved CPU cores to your program.